# ROS Answers SE migration: openni in rviz

Tags: rviz, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, i was trying to do these steps on my PC
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch#Quick_start

in Quick start part

with my kinect XBOX 360

all steps are Ok with me and disparity , RGB and grayscale picture shown normally outside rviz as below :
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?3gjedq55lva976o

but inside rviz don't show any thing like that
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?7qcr3tm8ovvczga

all steps to enable depth_registration are perfictly done but rviz don't appear any thing
is there any problem ? :))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48549/openni-in-rviz/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz you are subscribing to the normal un-registered pointcloud. You should change that to /camera/depth_registered/points if you have depth registration enabled.

If you still experience problems you should look at the text of the warning message and/or try setting a different fixed frame.

It may also help to check if any pointclouds are published at all using: rostopic hz

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0